# Not getting expected result from numerical evaluation of solution given by Solve

Tags: equation-solving

Let $m$ be a large integer and $z\in (0,1)$. I want to find $0 < k < m$ such that

$\frac{\sqrt{5-\frac{4k}{m}}-1}{2} + \frac{m-\frac{k}{2}\sqrt{5-\frac{4k}{m}}}{m^2\sqrt{5-\frac{4k}{m}}}$ 
is closest to $z$. So I set up an equation by letting the preceding expression equal $z$ and solved it for $k$. That is,

```
Solve[(Sqrt[5 - 4 k/m] - 1)/2 + (m - k/2 Sqrt[5 - 4 k/m])/(Sqrt[5 - 4 k/m] m^2) == z, k]
```

and it gave some complicated symbolic solutions, as the equation can be easily reduced to a cubic equation. Then I plugged in the actual values $m=20000$ and $z=0.1$,

```
N[% /. {m -> 20000, z -> 0.1}]
```

which evaluates as

> ```
> {{k -> 143373. + 0.0527344 I}, 
>  {k -> -3.2001*10^13 + 0. I}, 
>  {k -> -100572. - 0.0546875 I}}
> ```

which is clearly wrong. There should be a $k$ that is less than $m$, because the initial expression is at least $1/(2m)$ (plugging in $k = m$) and my choice of $z$ is greater than $1/(2m)$.

However, if I plug in the numbers directly into the equation,

```
Solve[(Sqrt[5 - 4 k/m] - 1)/2 + (m - k/2 Sqrt[5 - 4 k/m])/(Sqrt[5 - 4 k/m] m^2) 
    == z /. {m -> 20000, z -> 0.1}, k]
```

it gives the correct answer

> ```
> {{k -> 17800.5}, {k -> 25000.}}
> ```

So I am wondering whether this is a bug.

Comment: `Block[{z = 1/10, m = 20000}, Solve[eq == z, k, Reals]]` or in longer form `Block[{m = 20000, z = 1/10}, 
  Solve[(Sqrt[5 - 4 k/m] - 1)/
      2 + (m - k/2 Sqrt[5 - 4 k/m])/(Sqrt[5 - 4 k/m] m^2) == z, k, 
   Reals]] // N`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not encountered a bug but a weakness in machine precision arithmetic. If you switch to *Mathematica*'s more accurate arbitrary precision arithmetic, you can get away with an unconstrained (sloppy) problem statement.

```
sol = 
  Solve[
    (Sqrt[5 - 4 k/m] - 1)/2 + (m - k/2 Sqrt[5 - 4 k/m])/(Sqrt[5 - 4 k/m] m^2) == z, 
    k];
N[sol /. {m -> 20000, z -> 1/10}, 25] // Chop
```

> ```
> {{k -> 24999.99996527657202992317}, 
>  {k -> -3.200096001780046597611895*10^13}, 
>  {k -> 17800.46601084237600423031}}
> ```

But putting the problem to `Solve` with proper constraints (as others have observed) is a much better way to proceed because `Solve`, working under the constraints, give a solution that evaluates well even at machine precison.

```
sol = 
  Solve[
      (Sqrt[5 - 4 k/m] - 1)/2 + (m - k/2 Sqrt[5 - 4 k/m]) /
        (Sqrt[5 - 4 k/m] m^2) == z 
    && 
      0 < k < m, 
    k, Reals]
 N[sol /. {m -> 20000, z -> .1}]
```

> ```
> {{k -> 17800.5}, {k -> Undefined}}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

You need to build your assumptions into the problem. `Reduce` appears to work better than `Solve` for your problem. Let's look at both.

**Solve**

If one limits the solution to real numbers and wraps `Solve` with `Assumptions` which apply your inequalities a solution is found

```
sol = Assuming[
  m > k > 0 && z > 0,
  Solve[(Sqrt[5 - 4 k/m] - 1)/
      2 + (m - k/2 Sqrt[5 - 4 k/m])/(Sqrt[5 - 4 k/m] m^2) == z, k, 
   Reals
   ]
  ]
```

Substituting `{m, z} = {20000., 0.1}` results in

```
sol /. {m -> 20000., z -> 0.1}

{{k -> Undefined}, {k -> 17800.5}, {k -> 25000.}}
```

The middle rule matches your expected result.

**Reduce**

It appears to go smoother using `Reduce`.

```
sol = Reduce[(Sqrt[5 - 4 k/m] - 1)/
      2 + (m - k/2 Sqrt[5 - 4 k/m])/(Sqrt[5 - 4 k/m] m^2) == z && 
   m > k > 0 && z > 0, k, Reals]
```

Reduce produces a single answer

```
sol /. {m -> 20000., z -> 0.1}

k == 17800.5
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Minimize`. Since you want `k` such that the expression is "closest" you need to allow for the difference being positive or negative. I chose to square the difference to handle this.

```
diff[z_, m_] = 
  z - (Sqrt[5 - 4 k/m] - 1)/
    2 + (m - k/2 Sqrt[5 - 4 k/m])/(Sqrt[5 - 4 k/m] m^2);

soln = With[{m = 20000, z = 0.1}, Minimize[{diff[z, m]^2, 0 < k < m}, k]]

(*  {6.83353*10^-19, {k -> 17799.5}}  *)
```

The difference is

```
diff[z, m] /. {z -> 0.1, m -> 20000, soln[[-1, 1]]}

(*  -8.26651*10^-10  *)
```

Compared with the original result

```
diff[z, m] /. {z -> 0.1, m -> 20000, 
  Solve[(Sqrt[5 - 4 k/m] - 1)/
        2 + (m - k/2 Sqrt[5 - 4 k/m])/(Sqrt[5 - 4 k/m] m^2) == 
      z /. {m -> 20000, z -> 0.1}, k][[1, 1]]}

(*  0.0000388349  *)
```

`Minimize` gives the "closest"

Comment: Your answer gets my vote. Clearly answers question about closest.